# add records (rows) in an existing column in a spark data frame using join in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

These are the mock tables:

```
data1 = [['a', 1100], ['b', 2100], ['c', 3300], ['d', 4400]]
sales = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data1,['user_id','total_sale'])
data2 = [['b', 1000],['c',2000],['d',3000],['e',4000]]
target = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data2,['user_id','personalized_target'])
data3 = [['d', 4400],['e', 11000], ['f', 21000], ['g', 33000], ['h', 44000]]
sales_2 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data3,['user_id','total_sale'])
```

I want to insert data from `sales_2` to sales in the same column using a join statement. (That's a design requirement)

```
sales.join(sales_2,'user_id',"outer")
```

This statement creates another column with some null values instead of adding values to the original column.

The final result should be the same as produced by the union statement.

```
sales.union(sales_2).distinct().show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use coalesce function for this case

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> 
>>> sales.join(sales_2,'user_id',"outer").select('user_id',F.coalesce(sales['total_sale'],sales_2['total_sale']).alias('total_sale')).show()
+-------+----------+                                                            
|user_id|total_sale|
+-------+----------+
|      g|     33000|
|      f|     21000|
|      e|     11000|
|      h|     44000|
|      d|      4400|
|      c|      3300|
|      b|      2100|
|      a|      1100|
+-------+----------+
```